# IBM Maximo - How to add assignment to work order with automation script?

Tags: maximo, ibm-maximo-worker-insights

Using IBM Maximo 8, how would you add an assignment for the crewworkgroup HVAC via an automation script? What I am doing is creating a work order when an inspection is completed. I want to defualt all work orders to a certain crewworkgroup for this inspection.

```
 if mbo.getString("FUPOBJECT") == "":
                newSR = woSet.add()
                newSR.setValue("Description", "Inspection for " + str(mbo.getString("resultnum")))
                newSR.setValue("location", mbo.getString("location"))
                newSR.setValue("assetnum", mbo.getString("asset"))
                newSR.setValue("classstructureid", "CL104685")
                newSR.setValue("templateid", "TP100304")
                mbo.setValue("FUPOBJECT", "WORKORDER")
                mbo.setValue("FUPOBJECTID", newSR.getString("wonum"))
                mbo.setValue("DISPLAYMESSAGE", "Workorder " + str(newSR.getString("wonum")) + " created")
                print "Created WO " + str(newSR.getString("wonum"))
                woSet.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Set this via a jobplan.  Create a job plan that would have your crew work group in the planned labor section, and set the value in your script.